# Returning an object in another class file

Tags: c++

Try this

Date.h

```
#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H

#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Date{

  public:
    Date(int month, int day, int year);

    int getMonth() const;
    int getDay() const;
    int getYear() const;

  private:
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};

#endif
```

Date.cpp

```
#include "Date.h"
#include<string>
using namespace std;

Date::Date(int month, int day, int year) {
    this->month = month;
    this->day = day;
    this->year = year;
}

int Date::getMonth() const{
  return month;
}

int Date::getDay() const{
  return day;
}

int Date::getYear() const{
  return year;
}
```

Appointment.cpp

```
#include "Appointment.h"
#include "Date.h"
#include<sstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

Appointnment::Appointment(String description, int month, int day, int yr, int hr, int min)
{
    this->description = description;
    this->month = month;
    this->day = day;
    this->yr = yr;
    this->hr = hr;
    this->min = min;
}

void Appointinment::getDate()
{
    //cannot change calling object nor its date object member, just return it
}
```

}

I'm trying to implement the `getDate()` function, but I'm having trouble understanding how to return a Date given that this class is specified as an appointment. Are there any resources I can look at to tackle this specific problem?

Comment: return Date(this->month, this->day, this->yr); ?

Comment: so, your Date type is not used ?? why define Date type then?

Answer (score 0):

You code looks good. But when return soemthing, you need either a pointer to Data, or a refernce to Date, or straight object.

Either of following will work:

```
Date Appointinment::getDate() const

const Date& Appointinment::getDate() const

const Date* Appointinment::getDate() const
```

Judge from context, maybe first one is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
const Date& Appointinment::getDate()
{
     return Date(this->month, this->day, this->yr);
}
```

this is the most common way.